# Two sets of 9-digit numbers on back of Global Entry card

Tags: global-entry

There are two 9-digit numbers on the back of the Global Entry card. The one on the upper left corner is the Known Traveler Number or PASSID. But on the upper right hand corner there is another 9-digit number, slightly larger than the PASSID. What is the purpose of this second 9-digit number?

Answer (score 15):

It is simply the number if the Global ID card. You can see it in the machine readable area.

This allows to make a *Global ID card* invalid, for example if you lose it, without making your *Known Traveller Number* invalid, because it represents your person and is still valid.

Comment: Thanks, Aganju.   At least now I can stop wondering when and where I will use that number.